# How to create a showdown.js markdown extension

Tags: javascript, showdown

Using the following code, I get working output:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/showdown.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var converter = new Showdown.converter();
      alert(converter.makeHtml('*test* abc'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Returning `<p><em>test</em> abc</p>`

I would now like to add an extension.  The [github page](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown) suggests this can be done with:

```
<script src="src/extensions/twitter.js" />
var converter = new Showdown.converter({ extensions: 'twitter' });
```

However, modifying my code to:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/showdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/twitter.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var converter = new Showdown.converter({ extensions: 'twitter' });
      alert(converter.makeHtml('*test* abc'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Produces the error

```
"Uncaught Extension 'undefined' could not be loaded.  It was either not found or is not a valid extension."
```

Adding the following code (as listed under the [Filter example](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown#filter))

```
var demo = function(converter) {
  return [
    // Replace escaped @ symbols
    { type: 'lang', function(text) {
      return text.replace(/\\@/g, '@');
    }}
  ];
}
```

Produces an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`

I would like to create an extension like this one https://github.com/rennat/python-markdown-oembed to interpret a `![video](youtube_link)`, but it's unclear how to begin adding this support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last block you have a comma after 'lang', followed immediately with a function. This is not valid json.

*EDIT*

It appears that the readme was incorrect. I had to to pass an array with the string 'twitter'.

```
var converter = new Showdown.converter({extensions: ['twitter']});
converter.makeHtml('whatever @meandave2020');
// output "<p>whatever <a href="http://twitter.com/meandave2020">@meandave2020</a></p>"
```

I submitted a pull request to update this.

Comment: Indeed.  Bad example is bad.  Looking through the source, it looks like it might want to see that filter as `'function':function(){}`, although, that doesn't get me anywhere either.  I've tried a few variations on how the examples looked like they might want to see an extension but haven't gotten far.

Comment: It looks like the read me is incorrect. This seemed to work for me...```var converter = new Showdown.converter({extensions: ['twitter']})```

Comment: Aha, that'll get me started.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The way we write extensions has changed, I found some help with the following filter example : http://codepen.io/tivie/pen/eNqOzP

```
showdown.extension("example", function() {
  'use strict';
  return [
    {
      type: 'lang',
      filter: function(text, converter, options) {
        var mainRegex = new RegExp("(^[ \t]*:>[ \t]?.+\n(.+\n)*\n*)+", "gm");
        text = text.replace(mainRegex, function(match, content) {
          content = content.replace(/^([ \t]*):>([ \t])?/gm, "");
          var foo = converter.makeHtml(content);
          return '\n<blockquote class="foo">' + foo + '</blockquote>\n';
        });
        return text;
      }
    }
  ]
});
```