# how to style data and then store it in database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i am having a text area for users to write their posts in then save their posts inside a database, i would like to offer some little formatting like line breaks, bold , or italic fonts. is there any way using jquery or php to do this? i need the same exact idea of the editor that *stackoverflow* is using. any help?

here is my code for the textarea :-

```
<p>Message : </p><textarea cols="100" rows="10" name="message"></textarea>
```

also, is it better to use an editable `div` than a `textarea`?

Comment: do you mean CKE Editor or WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: google `markdown`. check this [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863978/how-to-create-a-showdown-js-markdown-extension)

Comment: Asking for that in such a way is considered Off-Topic or just Too-Broad. Also please restrain from asking Installing Support Question on Stackoverflow. Thank you!

Comment: The error you get is `E_SETUP_EXE_NOT_FOUND`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,,, you can use 'wysiwyg' editor, but if you want quick start ,,,,  just write the following inside header of html page (which has textarea):

```
<script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
        tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
</script>
```

Comment: Barak Allahu feek Akhy, this is the easiest solution, thanks alot

Comment: simple an efficient ... like it .

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of 'wysiwyg' editor (What-you-see-is-what-you-get). 
I prefer CKEditor - it comes with lots of tools and you can disable and enable what-ever you like.

http://ckeditor.com/demo

You can choose what options to show on the toolbar.

Comment: +1 I was about to post the exact same thing and point him to CKEditor :)

Comment: the need was `i need the same exact idea of the editor that stackoverflow is using`. answer is `pagedown`.

Comment: Using CKEditor for basic formatting is _overkill_.

Comment: it seems good but i dunno where i can find a way to install it? if you have a link please give it to me , thanks in advance :)